# Differentiating between identical USB scanners in TWAIN

Tags: c#, windows, registry, drivers

I am trying to use multiple identical USB flatbed scanners for a C# project using a .Net TWAIN library. The problem with the TWAIN drivers is they are not set up to handle multiple instances of identical USB devices, in this case two Epson V37 scanners. The two scanners show up in device manager as separate but only the first scanner being plugged in shows up in TWAIN. This is not the case when two distinct scanner models are attached. My question is; is there a way i can change the drivers/registry entries enough to make it look like different scanners to TWAIN